# Where can I find a Dual tire front disc brake kit for a recumbent trike

Tags: brakes, front, recumbent

I am accumulating parts to construct a recumbent trike with independent front suspension. I need to use disc brakes based on the framework I intend to use. I am looking for a dual set of front disc brakes to use in my application of my plans. I have seen no kits that are not front and rear only kits. I am looking for a dual front disc brake kit, to use on two front tires. What type of equipment should I search for?

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding product rec's, there are brakes and splitters designed to allow one lever to drive two calipers. This is uncommon, but not unknown in cycles and used for example disabled people, as well as niche markets such as trikes and cargo bikes. While a decent LBS is unlikely to stock a solution, it is likely to be able to find and order parts.

Hope do two that might be of interest - Tech 3 Duo lever has two levers on the same handset, driving two calipers. A better option for your use case might be something like the Hope Tech 3 X2 Uno - one lever driving two calipers. Problemsolvers has a dual cable (long pull) lever, which could be matched to mechanical disk calipers.  They also have a cable doubler that is used to split a cable and pull two brakes with one lever.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're not going to find a packaged set of brakes labelled as "two front brakes" because trikes are a vanishingly tiny market segment.
2. There's no difference between front and rear disc brakes. Same rotors, same calipers, same levers. The packaged cables or hoses will be different lengths, but you can work with that (I hope, if you're building a trike). Sometimes brake sets will be sold with different rotor sizes for the front and rear, but you can always find them matched.